# Number of even and odd subsets -- wrong question?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

The book on Discrete Mathematics I'm following poses the following problem:

> Prove that a nonempty set has the same number of odd subsets (i.e., subsets with odd number of elements) as even subsets.

A short proof is also given, but I have a counter-example: Consider the all the subsets of the set $ \{1, 2, 3\} = \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$. Now, number of odd subsets is 4, while that of even subsets is 3.

Where's the catch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\{\}$ is also a subset of the nonempty set.

Comment: Ah, but is it an even or an odd subset?!

Comment: $0$ is an even number, so what do you think? :) @dotslash